# How to disable the CAP NUM SCRL indicators in the status bar of a Windows C++ MFC app?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, statusbar

Default MDI application in MS Visual C++ 2010 shows CAP, NUM, SCRL indicators in the lower right corner.  These are not applicable for my application so would like to disable them.

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `CMainFrame` class you have this:

```
// CMainFrame

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CMainFrame, CMDIFrameWnd)

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainFrame, CMDIFrameWnd)
    ON_WM_CREATE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

static UINT indicators[] =
{
    ID_SEPARATOR,           // status line indicator
    ID_INDICATOR_CAPS,
    ID_INDICATOR_NUM,
    ID_INDICATOR_SCRL,
};
```

The `indicators` array is used somewhere later like this:

```
m_wndStatusBar.SetIndicators(indicators, sizeof(indicators)/sizeof(UINT));
```

Simply remove the `ID_INDICATOR_CAPS`, `ID_INDICATOR_NUM` and `ID_INDICATOR_SCRL` symbols at will.

Comment: beautiful, too obvious.  Thanks!